# java simpledateformat operations in excel

Tags: json, excel

I have a json file which contains timestamps in simpledateformat (2021-02-18T11:37:26Z) I would like to know how to substract 2 timestamps as I need the number of seconds lapsed between the first timestamp and the second.

Is there an easy form to do it with Excel?

Thanks